# How can I show an external URL as a build result in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

Specifically I have a jenkins job that builds and publishes a docker image to our own artifactory instance. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have the link to that artifactory (or docker hub, or anything else) link in place of the "Last Successful Artifacts" section shown on a build/project page?

[image]

For example, if the above image ^^^ had URLs instead of jenkins-archived artifacts. For example the page showing the artifactory page, or something simple like `docker pull centos:8.3.2011`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cant override the existing links in "Last Successful Artifacts" section, however you have several other options for both FreeStyle and Pipeline jobs:

- You can use the [Artifactory Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifactory/) to upload your artifacts - it will automatically add links to the artifacts on the build page alongside all relevant Artifactory build info.
- You can use the [Build Name and Description Setter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/) to set the build description with the links you want. This description will appear in the upper part of your build page and can include any HTML format you want including icons and links (Safe HTML option must be configured).
- You can use the [Sidebar Link Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sidebar-link/) to add a customized link to the sidebar menu of your build or project, you can configure the url, link text and the used icon according to your needs.
  For using it in pipeline Jobs see the [Following Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717135/how-can-i-use-jenkins-sidebar-link-plugin-in-pipeline-step/68070562#68070562)

The Artifactory Plugin is the easiest to use, setting the build description will give you maximum flexibility and the sidebar link is somewhat in the middle of both.