# Video url add to jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, grove

I have a pipline that runs like

```
node() {
    environment {
        DATA="${env.DATA}"
        BUILD_DESCRIPTION="${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }
   stage('Start autotest') {
      checkout scm

      def customImage = docker.build("python-web-tests:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f Dockerfile .")
      customImage.inside {
         sh "python ${env.CMD_PARAMS}"
      }
   }

   stage('Allure report') {
       allure([
           includeProperties: false,
           jdk: '',
           properties: [],
           reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
           results: [[path: 'report']]])
       cleanWs()
   }
    stage('Discard old builds') {
        if (currentBuild.currentResult == "UNSTABLE") {
            currentBuild.keepLog = true
        }
        if (currentBuild.currentResult == "FAILURE") {
            currentBuild.keepLog = true
        }
   }
}
```

this, I also have a link to a video that I would like to add to the build page, by type selenoid/video/5554bb735ae02660345220363f060
how to make such a stage?

I need to add a video report after the test, please tell me how to do this.You can use a link, of course, but I would like the video to be displayed in the build

Comment: See the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62717135/13110835), it makes use with the [sidebar link plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sidebar-link/).